# How to wait in a non MonoBehaviour class, without returning anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I am making a game and I ran into a problem. I need to wait for about half a sec, And I am in a non MonoBehaviour  class + I can't return anything, because I need to return other data. 
This is what I tried:

```
// opening a MonoBehaviour  class and run this from it

void StartCoroutineHelp(){
    StartCoroutine(*Corountine Name*);
}
```

It wont work, because in a Corountine you need to return data,

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve, normally you would use an event eg OnCompletion or something for other classes to pick up when to go get the data etc.. unity by default runs on the main thread, if you wait on that, everything else will wait

Comment: Just wondering: Why can't you return anything?